# How to install flask-mysql for python3?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I tried to install flask-mysql from pip3 to python3, but it throws exception.
Here is log.

```
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-j2hw4zsz/MySQL-python/setup.py) egg_info for package MySQL-python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-j2hw4zsz/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from setup_posix import get_config
  File "/tmp/pip-build-j2hw4zsz/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build-j2hw4zsz/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>

from setup_posix import get_config

File "/tmp/pip-build-j2hw4zsz/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>

from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

So, how to install flask-mysql to python3?

P.S. I tried to install both with "pip3 install flask-mysql" and "pip install Flask...whl".

Comment: There is currently pending issue on this sunject https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/issues/8 .

Answer (score 6):

Flask-MySQL uses MySQL-Python, which doesn't support Python 3, and there has been an [open issue about it](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/issues/8) for over a year.  Use Flask-MySQLdb instead, which uses MySQLclient.

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

Or use SQLAlchemy, a much more powerful interface for working with databases.

```
pip install flask-sqlalchemy mysqlclient
```