# db.create_all() issues with python 3.7 for MAC

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I can tell many people have had issues with this but having tried all possible solutions i have made my own post which hopefully can help solve this issue specifically for me.

When i try running db.create_all() i get this error (attached in pic):
[Error observed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AhNQ.png)

I understand this is because mysqldb does not support python 3. But i have also tried importing the pymysql and this didnt work either (unless of course i did that step wrong? I basically added the lines:

```
import pymysql
```

and then

```
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

into my app.py file.

I am still really new to all of this. Anybody who's had this could they explain in simple steps please?

Comment: I also tried brew install mysql-connector-c 
followed by pip install MySQL-python
and this gave me Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653076/how-to-install-flask-mysql-for-python3

Comment: I get the same error here: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ld/zjvdzzrs0jqdrkd4gkkxht3h0000gn/T/pip-install-_pfy_5jd/mysqlclient/

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to using MySQLdb package for python3. Assuming you have [pip3](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) installed,

> sudo pip3 install mysqlclient

should install the necessary packages, you can use

```
import MySQLdb
```

as usual afterwards. That's how I've installed it and have been using it since.

Comment: Sudo pip3 install mysqlclient gives me the following error:
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-5z45xrl4/mysqlclient/

Comment: Try executing `sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`, then do the same.

Comment: I tried that and it suggests that its upto date. I still got the same error following that :(

I suppose i have no option but to carry on with sqlite as i have managed to get that working in the past.